# Get /Put Device Alias using Teamviewer REST API

Tags: json, vb.net, rest, teamviewer

Im looking to get a list of all the devices on my work admin teamviewer account using vb.net. I would also like to be able to change the "Alias"  of a given device using it's device id. i know very little about API's. i found the following example but i am not sure how to adapt it to get the json response.

instead of the accesstoken, i believe i need to use the client id and secret id along with the authorization code in order to use this. if i run it in it's current start i get a 401 unauthorized error. Any help would be appreciated.

i also have no idea how to use "PUT" to change the Alias using the device id which will both be entered in textboxes. ex alias = textbox1.text and device_id = textbox2.text

```
Private Sub SurroundingSub()
Dim accessToken As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Dim apiVersion As String = "v1"
Dim tvApiBaseUrl As String = "https://webapi.teamviewer.com"
Dim address As String = tvApiBaseUrl & "/api/" & apiVersion & "/devices"

Try
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Headers.Add("Bearer", accessToken)
    request.Method = "GET"
    Dim webResp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
msgbox(__unusedException1__.ToString)
End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Get all devices code:

```
Private Sub get_teamviewer_devices()
    Dim accessToken As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Dim apiVersion As String = "v1"
    Dim tvApiBaseUrl As String = "https://webapi.teamviewer.com"
    Dim address As String = tvApiBaseUrl & "/api/" & apiVersion & "/devices"
    Dim result_json As String = Nothing
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
        request.Method = "GET"
        Dim webResp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using reader = New StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream)
            result_json = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        TextBox1.Text = result_json
    Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        MsgBox(__unusedException1__.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is the PUT portion to change an alias:

```
Public Sub change_alias(ByVal device_id As String, ByVal alias_str As String)
    Dim accessToken As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Dim apiVersion As String = "v1"
    Dim tvApiBaseUrl As String = "https://webapi.teamviewer.com"
    Dim address As String = tvApiBaseUrl & "/api/" & apiVersion & "/devices/" & device_id
    Dim result As String
    Dim alias_str_ As String = Chr(34) & alias_str & Chr(34)
    Try
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
        request.Method = "PUT"
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        Using requestWriter2 As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
            requestWriter2.Write("{""Alias"" : " & alias_str_ & "}")
        End Using
        Dim webResp As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using reader = New StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream)
            result = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        TextBox1.Text = (result)
    Catch __unusedException1__ As Exception
        MsgBox(__unusedException1__.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```